# Getting a Jquery selector for month and day only

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

First at all, thanks for all the help you can give me and sorry for my English since it's not my native language.

I am looking for a solution (with jquery selectpicker or another plugin) that allow me to set up a textfield and restrict the user to select only a day and a month.

Explanation:
I have a case when the user set a yearly recurrent reminder, so I have a field that will allow him to select the day and the month of those yearly reminders. 
I have look a lot and I haven't been able to find what I am looking for. Right now this is my best approach (the code is not mine) http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/7755/.

I tried to change the code to this:

```
$(function() {
$('.date-picker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: false,
    changeDay: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd MM',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay, 1));
    }
});
});
```

But without luck.

is there any way I can accomplish this? I was thinking a simple select, but I want to make it better than that. Also, I could leave the selecpicker just the way it is and in the dateFormat parameter use 'dd MM', but when the user opens the calendar it will display the year and that will cause confusion.

Thanks in advance all help you can give me.

Comment: Just to add a clarification, I am using this one: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html

Answer (score 1):

Modified to do what I think you're after:

http://jsfiddle.net/f6neo7ns/1/

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd MM',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear,inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
    }
});
```

- Removing the CSS will show the day picker.
- JS is changed to return the full picked date in the format `dd MM`

If you want to hide the year completely, you can simply add this CSS:

```
.ui-datepicker-year{display: none}
```

As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/f6neo7ns/2/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I copied your exact code and seems like it is still using the full format. I have a lot of calendars in my page so I don't know if that affects something. Also, otherwise your example, my calendar does not show the month and year in different fields (I didn't make the frontend). http://prntscr.com/ai4e0z

Comment: @arkofdan If you're initializing the datepicker multiple times then you may be overwriting these changes. Try giving it an ID and selecting that instead of the `.date-picker` class.

Comment: I am using a class called: "yearly-selector" for this field (and I am sure the field doesn't have other clases) https://gist.github.com/danilor/dece432ac737d014748b

Comment: Try removing the `$(function() {})` wrapper, if you're already using it inside a document ready then it shouldn't be needed. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I removed the "$(function(){})" as you said and is still being overwritted by the main selectpicker. Is weird. And if I remove the code you just send me the field doesnt do anything. Since I didn't make that frontend is hard for me. I will keep trying. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use a datePicker, here's how to only display the month and date

```js
$(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker({
        changeMonth     : true,
        yearRange       : "2016:2016",
        showButtonPanel : true,
        dateFormat      : 'dd MM',
        beforeShow      : function(el, inst) {
            setTimeout(function() {
             inst.dpDiv.find('.ui-datepicker-year').hide();
            },0);
        },
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<label for="startDate">Date :</label>
<input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
```

---

However, I think you're overcomplicating it, if you want just two dropdowns, one for month and one for date, just use that, you don't need a datepicker, and in my opinion it's a lot better UX with two regular dropdowns, rather than an input that shows a date with a datepicker, when the user isn't supposed to select a real date, just a day in a month.

If the styles of the native selects seem boring, add other styles

```js
$(function() {
    $('#month').on('change', function() {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setMonth(+(this.value) + 1);
        date.setDate(0);
        var days = date.getDate(),
            opts = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < days; i++) {
            opts.push($('<option />', {
                text: i + 1,
                value: i + 1
            }));
        }
        $('#day').html(opts);
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

```css
select {
    height: 29px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-padding-end: 20px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 2px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    background-image: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/15xvbd5.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(#FAFAFA, #F4F4F4 40%, #E5E5E5);
    background-position: 97% center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    color: #555;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Select a date for the yearly reminder</h2>
<br/>
<select id="day"></select>
<select id="month">
    <option value="0">January</option>
    <option value="1">February</option>
    <option value="2">March</option>
    <option value="3">April</option>
    <option value="4">May</option>
    <option value="5">June</option>
    <option value="6">July</option>
    <option value="7">August</option>
    <option value="8">September</option>
    <option value="9">October</option>
    <option value="10">November</option>
    <option value="11">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Trust me that if it were my choice, I would delete all those weird fields we are using. But my boss really want that to be just like the date picker we are using in the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.ui-datepicker-year{
    display:none;
}
```

to stop the year from displaying in the datepicker.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. But I dont want to hide all my calendar years since I have a lot of them in my page. And otherwise other examples I have seen, mine does not separate the month and year. (I didn't make the frontend) http://prntscr.com/ai4e0z